# Difference between two DateTime values -MySql

Tags: mysql, datetime

I am working on an application where I need to get the difference between two columns having data type as DateTime and if the difference is less than one hour, it should give 1 and if greater than 1 and less than 2, it should return 2 and so on. I have been trying different queries but none of them looks working quite well.

If I need to do something in coding, please suggest me that as well. I am using Java to design the application. For what I tried is

```
SELECT floor((TIMEDIFF('2019-01-08 18:23:13', '2019-01-08 18:40:36'))) AS DIFF
SELECT floor((DATEDIFF('2019-01-08 18:23:13', '2019-01-08 18:40:36'))) AS DIFF
SELECT floor(TIMEDIFF(hour,'2019-01-08 18:23:13', '2019-01-08 18:40:36'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`TIMESTAMPDIFF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff), which will take the `floor` automatically, and then add one:

```
SELECT  TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, '2019-01-08 18:23:13', '2019-01-08 18:40:36')+1
```

Output

```
1
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5ae66484a8cdbf014422192c84c45e5e)